# Jupyter autofill suggestion textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, jupyter

I am working with Jupyter Notebook and am trying to get suggestions to work with a text box as you type characters in. A good example I found is  [here.](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

I want to give suggestions as the user types characters, so the list of suggestions will change for every character typed.

I am new to Jupyter and am still trying to learn all the functionality. I need to rely on the base Jupyter tools, such as the ipython widgets (can't install other packages). Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using bokeh's `AutocompleteInput` for this?
Check out the following example from:

[Access data from bokeh widgets in a jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40483510/access-data-from-bokeh-widgets-in-a-jupyter-notebook)

```
from bokeh.models.widgets.inputs import AutocompleteInput
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import show
from bokeh.models import CustomJS

output_notebook()

callback = CustomJS(code="""
if (IPython.notebook.kernel !== undefined) {
    var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel;
    cmd = "widget_value = '" + cb_obj.value + "'";
    kernel.execute(cmd, {}, {});
}
""")

txt_input = AutocompleteInput(completions=['val1', 'val2'], callback=callback)

show(txt_input)

print(widget_value)
```

EDIT: I've just seen you can't install packages. However, the above answer requires `bokeh` to be installed.