# RuntimeError: This event loop is already running. This happens when I run my code in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, runtime-error

I'm trying to implement this logic in my code but there's always an error the RuntimeError: This event loop is already running"
This happens when I run my code in jupyter, but its ok in Visual Studio Code. Any idea on how to solve it?

```
from prompt_toolkit import prompt

from prompt_toolkit.completion import WordCompleter

#Dictionary of fruits and prices:

fruits = {
    "apple": 2.5,
    "orange": 3.0,
    "pinapple": 5.0,
    "banana": 1.5,
    "kiwi": 4.0,
    "mango": 6.0
}

#Complete fruits:

fruits_completer = WordCompleter(list(fruits.keys()))

#Ask user for the name of the fruit:

fruits= prompt("Type the name of the fruit: ", completer=fruits_completer)

#Show the price of the choosen fruit:

price = fruits.get(fruit)

if price:

    print(f"The price of the {fruit} is: {price}")

else:

    print("The fruit is not in the list")
```

This should happen
When I run it tells me to type the name of the fruit
then if I type app, it show me apple as an option, then if I choose it (and press enter)
it should show me the price of that fruit

```
Type the name of the fruit: app

Type the name of the fruit: apple

The price is: 2.5
```

Comment: sorry for the mess, it's my first interaction here

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please checkout the [tour], [ask] and [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: I don't think you realize that, "Prompt_toolkit is a terminal library: an ncurses or GNU Readline replacement. Web based front-ends are out af [sic] scope for this library."(Source: [Issue report: Doesn't work in Jupyter Notebook](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit/issues/1066)). (Also, be sure to click through on the links towards the bottom where you see 'Does this work with Jupyter Notebook?')This would be easily implemented in Jupyter using `input()` for the "Type the name of the fruit: " or make an interface with ipywidgets to select the fruit from among the options.

Comment: I'm adding a separate comment to highlight what I referenced in part parenthetically in my first comments: Also see [Issue report: Does this work with Jupyter Notebook?](https://github.com/tmbo/questionary/issues/117#issuecomment-778409688) and [Issue report: Add compatibility for Jupyter Notebooks](https://github.com/tmbo/questionary/issues/118#issuecomment-779244880). Both of these are more pertinent to the 'RuntimeError: This event loop is already running.' issue featured in the title

Comment: @Wayne thanks. I didnt know it. I wanted to implement this logic since I have a dictionary with a lot of information and I think that making that kind of recommended search while I type would be very useful for my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74829153/8508004) and your code, an option:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interactive

fruits = { "apple": 2.5, "orange": 3.0, "pinapple": 5.0, "banana": 1.5, "kiwi": 4.0, "mango": 6.0 }

drop1 = widgets.Dropdown(options=fruits.keys(), value='apple', description='Fruit:', disabled=False)

def update_dropdown(fruit):
    info = (f"The price of the {fruit} is: {fruits[fruit]}")
    print(info)  
        
w = interactive(update_dropdown, fruit=drop1) 
display(w)
```

For a place to try this code without first installing ipywidgets on your machine, go [here](https://github.com/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder) and click on '`launch binder`'. Paste in the code block above when the session starts and the notebook comes up. Then run the code and change the drop-down to choose different fruit.

---

##### Add autocomplete

There's a simple autocomplete example that works [here](https://github.com/germanesosa/ipywidget-autocomplete). You just put `autoFill.py` from [there](https://github.com/germanesosa/ipywidget-autocomplete) in the same directory with your notebook. (This will work in the same sessions I referenced above if you add `autoFill.py`.) Then try:

```py
import autoFill as af
from ipywidgets import HTML, HBox

def open(value):
    show.value=f"The price of the {value.new} is: {fruits[value.new]}"
    
options = ['Football', 'Basketball', 'Voleyball', 'Basketcase', 'Showcase', 'Footer', 'Header', 'Viewer', 'Footage', 'Showtime', 'Show Business']
fruits = { "apple": 2.5, "orange": 3.0, "pinapple": 5.0, "banana": 1.5, "kiwi": 4.0, "mango": 6.0 }
autofill = af.autoFill(list(fruits.keys()),callback=open)

show = HTML('Result will be displayed here!')

display(HBox([autofill,show]))
```

As you start typing `app`, it will opt you to choose `apple` or `pinapple`[sic].

Alternatively, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40515198/8508004) suggests Bokeh has an autocompleteInput widget. That code didn't work for me, but a variation on [the current autocompleteinput example here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/3.0.0/docs/examples/interaction/widgets/autocompleteinput.html) worked:

```py
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.models import AutocompleteInput
from bokeh.sampledata.world_cities import data
output_notebook()
completion_list = data["name"].tolist()

auto_complete_input =  AutocompleteInput(title="Enter a city:", completions=completion_list)

show(auto_complete_input)
```

After I ran the following in the cell above it:

```py
%pip install bokeh
import bokeh
bokeh.sampledata.download()
```

Although, **the fact there was choices coming up below for the Bokeh widget wasn't really obvious unless I scrolled looking for them** as the space didn't get well generated below. Both in classic notebook and JupyterLab.

And obviously that would need to be adapted. I just used the example code and even getting that to work wasn't as straightforward as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was really helpful I thought I was going to wait some days at least for a reply, but really thanks.  it's always great to know more about python and its libraries. If someone has the same problem or want to do something similar I think it would be helpful if they check this [link](https://pythonguides.com/python-tkinter-autocomplete/) too, it's about Python Tkinter Autocomplete.